# Open .laz point clouds not available in QGIS 3.18

Tags: qgis-3, lidar, import, windows-10, point-cloud

The recent release of QGIS 3.18 [supports point cloud data](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog318/index.html#feature-add-point-clouds-to-browser). As can be seen on the screenshot in the linked Visual Changelog (above), `.laz` files should be supported.

However, in my installation on Windows 10 (standalone installer) it looks differently: I don't have the option `PDAL Point Clouds` and `EPT Point Cloud` in the data source management interface. I only have one entry `Point Cloud`, see screenshot below. With this option, I am not able to open `.laz` files. If I select one of the files to open, nothing happens. Only supported format is `ept.json` as can be seen on the screenshot.

If I just drag and drop a `.laz` file from the explorer to the QGIS window, I get this error message: `[path].laz is not a valid or recognized data source`. The same is true when I convert the `.laz` file to `.las` unsing [lastools](https://rapidlasso.com/lastools/).

I also tried different lidar files sources to be sure that the problem is not connected to a corrupted file. I tried e.g. 2010 USGS Lidar data from San Francisco bay area: https://coast.noaa.gov/htdata/lidar1_z/geoid12a/data/1406/

So how can I open a .laz file? I'm not sure if I miss something or if it a bug.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could be wrong but you should reinstall QGIS 3.18 with the new installer. QGIS standalone installers on Windows are all based on OSGEO4W. At the moment, 2 OSGEO4W installers and only the new one allows for point cloud support.
See announcement at https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-user/2021-February/048137.html

You may try the new standalone installer based on MSI installer https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-user/2021-February/048199.html

You can also see a video about the new MSI installer by Hans van der Kwast in YouTube  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wbCbLs_XEMA

Comment: No point cloud support in current standalone installers according to 1st link `It also has PDAL 2.2 which is required for native support of point clouds in 
QGIS - something that you find lacking in the "old" OSGeo4W repository and in
turn in the current standalones.` Try the MSI installer: the new standalone installer should support point cloud

Comment: indeed, using the new OSGeo4W installer, adding laz-files is possible. Thanks a lot for hinting to right post, the information is quite hidden.

Comment: FYI, as you say quite hidden but on the QGIS Twitter account, both links mentioned. That's where my answer coming from.

Comment: There is a bug tracking this silent fail https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/41764

Comment: QGIS standalone installer for 3.18 is offline right now "because of some serious issues found after release." Will be back with release 3.18.1 with fixes. So anyhow, right now the only way to install 3.18 is OSGeo4W.

Comment: Update: QGIS 3.18.1 released with the new installer and fixes for 3.18 serie https://twitter.com/JuergenEFischer/status/1373923127852474369