# Changing the path to the untwine executable in QGIS? - Point cloud data will not display in QGIS 3.18.1

Tags: qgis, lidar, windows-10

**Describe the bug**

QGIS will load my LAZ file, but it will only show the file extents. It won't show points in 2D or 3D map. I have installed and uninstalled QGIS several times and I have used the rebooted OSGEO4W installer as well as the [Standalone installers from OSGeo4W testing packages (MSI)](https://qgis.org/downloads/QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.18.1-3.msi).

**How to Reproduce**

Drag and drop an LAZ file from the browser onto the map. The bounding box will be displayed immediately. Here is the [LAZ file I used - nb_2017_2418000_7497000](https://geonb.snb.ca/downloads2/lidar/2017/erd2/laz/nb_2017_2418000_7497000.laz)

The `ept` folder was created (`ept_nb_2017_2418000_7497000`) but it was empty.
The log messages for Point clouds included:

```
2021-04-10T13:20:22 INFO Using executable C:/Program Files/QGIS31~1.1/apps/qgis/./untwine.exe
```

However, the actual path on my laptop is `"C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.18.1\apps\qgis\untwine.exe"`. I noticed this problem with the `untwine` path in the `C:\OSGEO4W` install and the `C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.18.1` install.

Can I change the path to the `untwine` executable in QGIS?

**QGIS and OS versions**

QGIS version
3.18.1-Zürich
QGIS code revision
202f1bf
Compiled against Qt
5.15.2
Running against Qt
5.15.2
Compiled against GDAL/OGR
3.2.2
Running against GDAL/OGR
3.2.2
Compiled against GEOS
3.9.1-CAPI-1.14.2
Running against GEOS
3.9.1-CAPI-1.14.2
Compiled against SQLite
3.35.2
Running against SQLite
3.35.2
Compiled against PDAL
2.2.0
Running against PDAL
2.2.0 (git-version: 24dd45)
PostgreSQL Client Version
13.0
SpatiaLite Version
5.0.1
QWT Version
6.1.3
QScintilla2 Version
2.11.5
Compiled against PROJ
8.0.0
Running against PROJ
Rel. 8.0.0, March 1st, 2021
OS Version
Windows 10 Version 1709
Active python plugins
db_manager;
MetaSearch;
processing

Windows 10 Enterprise

Comment: Are you aware of this? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/388600/88814

Comment: Yes I am aware that only some of the installers for version 3.18 include the point cloud support.  I am certain I have used the proper installer to get the point cloud features.  I have used the same installer on another laptop and it works.  For some odd reason I am having this problem only on my work laptop.

Comment: @Ian Turton: To me, the question seems focued: "Can I change the path to the untwine executable in QGIS?" and not related to one of the reasons mentioned (licensing, pricing, release dates, submission of bug reports and enhancement requests, etc.).

Comment: Then it would be better to make the question clearer and not start with the word bug which makes it look a lot like a "bug report" to me

Comment: those 2 paths seem to be identical to my eye (though I'm not expert on windows path mangling).

Answer (score 1):

untwine executable path can be changed by setting up environment variable `QGIS_UNTWINE_EXECUTABLE`.

But, if QGIS reports `INFO Using executable ...\untwine.exe` it means the executable was found and used correctly. The difference between the reported path and the actual path on disk is just some path mangling in the logs.

I can load the file on macOS, QGIS 3.18, but it takes around a minute on my computer to preprocess the LAZ file (you can see the progress bar for background task that creates point cloud index)

[image: QGIS Point Cloud]

Comment: if the file does not load on your computer I suggest to create a QGIS bug report